# Configurable error messages in microservice architecture

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices

We are using `microservice` architecture using `spring-boot`. For now, we are creating the messages  in our code based on certain conditions.

We want to make the messages **configurable** by placing them in a `database` so that they can be changed and managed from a central position.

We have around 8-9 microservices and we have decided to add a new microservice (named `commons-utils`) in which we will create a database to place all the messages.

So, if a change is required in the message, we can just update the database.
We can add different types of success and error messages, as well as the `API` custom response messages in the DB as they will be common to all microservices.

e.g.

```
ID | Code   | Messge                                        
1    ORD0001  Order placed by Client: {ClientName} 
2    ORD0002  Order Completed.
.
3    INV0001  Invoice generated for ordernumber: {Ordernumber}
.
11   NOT0001  Order accepted by Supplier: {SupplierName}
..

2..  A0001    Order was cancelled.
```

We will get all these messages after a successful login and store it in a `cache` probably, so that this `commons-utils` microservice is not called for getting every message and then get the message based on the code and populate it with the required values and then send it.

That's the implementation in our mind. I wanted to know if there are any better ways to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What goals are you trying to achieve? Who will consume these messages, and why do they care about them being centralized?

Comment: The goal is to place all the type of messages in a central location, so that whenever a message is to be changed, they can be changed from one central location.

And we are planning to place every message in the database e.g. the error or success messages in the response of rest APIs, the messages, the **frontend** would display on different events. e.g. Order initiated, order processed successfully etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of error messages can get quite large, the approach you are trying seems to be the best (Standing by the requirement that you need a central service). The hibernate cacheing mechanisms can give you good performance even though you are making db calls to fetch message.

If your no. of messages can be controlled/maintained within a file, please make use of a configuration server as it can be up and running without much coding. Please refer:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/
This will allow you to make use of different profiles (corresponding to dev, qa, uat prod enviroments etc) easily and the properites can be managed using git.
This would help you get started with a config server: https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

But in both scenarios, please keep in mind that if this service goes down, all your message scenarios would break!.

Comment: We are planning to add a large number of messages (the API response success and error messages, the messages for the front end, the message for notifications etc,) and the list is gonna increase over time as new messages are added with time. Not sure, if its wise to place all of them in a single file.

Comment: if no. of messages can get large please use databases itself.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it makes much more sense that every microservice is responsible for its own business logic and the relevant error messages.

So the "Orders" microservice has all the relevant error messages that it may face.

By putting all the error messages in one place, you create a coupling between service X and the `commons-utils`. This way service X will not be able to send errors before `commons-utils` will know of such an error.

This will also force you to have multiple commits when new business logic is added (one commit in service X and one DB change in the `commons-utils` service) and later on to sync their deployments and releases.

I would keep the error messages in a configuration file **per service**, where they sit right next to the code that works with them.

Comment: And apart from the release management, since *microservices* are meant to stand by them selves, this approach is much better.

Answer (score 1):

There are a *lot* of considerations here.

Firstly (as @riorio says), you're coupling the microservice, the front end, and the utils service. The major benefit of microservice architectures is to decouple business domains, but you're introducing a dependency.

Next, you probably want to use internationalization to manage the strings displayed to the end user. This is well supported out-of-the-box in pretty much every application framework.

Then, you have to consider the architectural goals of micro services. Each bounded context is its own, coherent, independent implementation of a business domain. Applications orchestrate their logic across these contexts; each application can have its own logical flows. By trying to capture the messages in a single place, you end up defining those logical flows in that one database. The messages can be different in different contexts, and often have a fair amount of additional information. I would say the (front-end) application is responsible for understanding its own logic flows, and the end-user messages that go with it.

Finally, Your design relies on caching for performance; caching introduces complexity, and complexity causes bugs. The data you cache presumably changes rarely if ever, and probably only in the context of an application deployment - I wouldn't expect the business to want to change "Order created!" messages frequently. You now have to handle cache invalidation, testing the caching, and managing the caching configuration.

So, there's no right or wrong solution to this problem, but you're introducing coupling and caching complexity, you're centralizing application decisions, and you're not using "out of the box" ways of managing strings. I'm not sure those decisions are paid back by the benefits.